# Secure gateway between Bluemix CF apps and containers

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

Can I use Secure-Gateway between my Cloud Foundry apps on Bluemix and my Bluemix docker container database (mongo)? It does not work for me.
Here the steps I have followed:

**upload secure gw client docker image on bluemix**

> docker push  registry.ng.bluemix.net/NAMESPACE/secure-gateway-client:latest

**run the image with token as a parameter**

> cf ic run registry.ng.bluemix.net/edevregille/secure-gateway-client:latest GW-ID

when i look at the logs of the container secure-gateway, I get the following:

> [INFO] (Client PID 1) Setting log level to INFO 
>   [INFO] (Client PID 1) There are no Access Control List entries, the ACL Deny All flag is set to: true
>   [INFO] (Client PID 1) The Secure Gateway tunnel is connected

and the secure-gateway dashboard interface shows that it is connected too.

But then, when I try to add the MongoDB database (running also on my Bluemix at  134.168.18.50:27017->27017/tcp) as a destination from the service secure-gateway dashboard, nothing happened: the destination is not created (does not appear).

I am doing something wrong? Or is it just that this not a supported use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The Secure Gateway is a service used to integrate resources from a remote (company) data center into Bluemix. Why do you want to use the SG to access your docker container on Bluemix?

2) From a technical point of view the scenario described in the question should work. However, you need to add rule to the access control list (ACL) to allow access to the docker container with your MongoDB. When you are running the SG it has a console to type in commands. You could use something like `allow 134.168.18.50:27017` as command to add the rule.

BTW: There is a [demo using the Secure Gateway](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/onprem-integration-demo) to connect to a MySQL running in a VM on Bluemix. It shows how to install the SG and add a ACL rule.

Added: If you are looking into how to secure traffic to your Bluemix app, then just use https instead of http. It is turned on automatically.

Comment: 1) the app on CF can access docker container db without SG. But it is going through public internet so not secure at all. Maybe I should work with another service to secure the access to BM container from a CF app?

Comment: The SG is thought kind of a VPN out of your data center into Bluemix. Here you have everything inside the SoftLayer/IBM cloud. What you are looking for is SSL into Bluemix. Check this out: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/08/18/inbound-ssl-bluemix/  Basically use https instead of http